# search items in database and display dropdown list

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-search

I have the following app architecture (generalized for simplification):

main `Layout` consists of `ActionBar` with custom `View` and scrollable `Tabs`, and a `ViewPager` hosting multiple `ListFragments`. Each `ListFragment` has its own set of data (1 row = `ImageView` + `TextView`) which is loaded from an SQLite database. In my `ActionBar's` custom `View` a have a "search" `EditText`.

When the user starts typing something, I'd like to perform an "on-the-go" search in the database and display matching names (those names should be clickable) in form of a dropdown list. I saw some examples how to perform a search in a `ListView`, but nothing related to database search.

So the question is: *how to display database search results as dropdown list and refresh it anytime the user adds or removes a character?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to implement [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html). This allows suggestions as the user is typing. You can bind the data to be searched for, using [Adapters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html).

This should solve your problem.

An example that might be helpful can be found [here](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-autocompletetextview-sqlite-and-dependent-fields/).

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the `OnQueryTextListener()` interface and override the `onQueryTextChange(String text)` method - this method gets called on character changes. Something like

```
searchTextInstance.setOnQueryTextListener(new CustomQueryListener());
```

Within `onQueryTextChange(Sting text)` query your database and then call

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter()
//... populate the adapter with the query results and call
searchTextInstance.setSuggestionAdapter(adapter)
```

where CustomAdapter is a class that extends SimpleCursorAdapter and this instance is populated by your query results (the results to be displayed in the drop down menu).

To make the selection clickable you can then set a custom OnSuggestionListener() to your `searchTextInstance`, i.e.

```
searchTextInstance.setOnSuggestionListener(new CustomSuggestionListener());
```

where `CustomSuggestionListener` implements `OnSuggestoinListener` - the only method of the interface, `onSuggestionClick(int postion)` will accomplish your goal

Answer (score 0):

To view the searched result in drop down you can use **PopupWindow**

I implement it in room database after getting search results

**getting the data from database**

```
   private fun searchCustomer(param: String) {
    var listOfCustomer = ArrayList<LocalCustomer>()
    localCustomerRepository.searchLocalCustomers(param).observe(this,
        Observer<List<LocalCustomer>> { localCustomerList ->
            listOfCustomer = localCustomerList as ArrayList

            if (listOfCustomer.size > 0) {
                val locationAdapter = CustomerAdapter(context, listOfCustomer)
                setupPopupWindow(listOfCustomer)
            } else {
                Utils.showMsg(this, "No result found")
            }
        })


}
```

**Setting up Popup window**

```
 private fun setupPopupWindow(listOfCustomer: ArrayList<LocalCustomer>) {
    val inflater = this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_list, null)
    val popupWindow =
        PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true)
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(svSearch, 0, 0)
    val locationAdapter = CustomerAdapter(context, listOfCustomer)
    val listView = layout.findViewById(R.id.lvMenu) as ListView
    listView.adapter = locationAdapter
    listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { adapterView, 
    view, position, id ->

        popupWindow.dismiss()
    }

}
```

**spinner_list**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/text_vvvvlight_gry"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**SearchView**

```
svSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(param: String?): Boolean {
            if (param != null && param != "")
                searchCustomer(param)
            return true
        }
    })
```

**CustomerAdapter** would be a baseAdapter or you can use ArrayAdapter